# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#2>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<WhiteBoardApp.Models.BrokerOutright>

Tags: c#, linq

I have an issue returning some data in my application using the following C# code

```
[Queryable(AllowedQueryOptions = System.Web.Http.OData.Query.AllowedQueryOptions.Select)]
public override IQueryable<BrokerOutright> Get()
{
 return db.BrokerOutrights.Where(b => b.BidBroker == User.Identity.Name 
                                  || b.OfferBroker == User.Identity.Name)
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    x.Id,
                    x.Product,
                    x.Term,
                    (x.AskB=='dev')?x.AskB:null,
                    (x.AskB=='dev')?x.AVol:null
                }
                );
}
```

The above code threw me following exception

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable

May I know a good explicit conversion?

Comment: Why convert to a new type at all?  If you're selecting from `db.BrokerOutrights` then presumably you're already selecting the type you want?  Just remove the `.Select()` clause entirely.

Comment: I would like to use some comparisons in select clause and that is the reason I have included .Select()

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean, do you have an example of that?  Because the code you've shown doesn't present a need for a `.Select()`.

Comment: I have edited my question in '.Select()'

Answer (score 4):

Yes, because you're projecting to an anonymous type:

```
.Select(x => new
{
    x.Id,
    x.Product,
    x.Term 
})
```

It sounds like you want to use an object initializer for the `BrokerOutright` type:

```
.Select(x => new BrokerOutright
{
    Id = x.Id,
    Product = x.Product,
    Term = x.Term 
})
```

Having said that, if `db.BrokerOutrights` is already an `IQueryable<BrokerOutright>` you may just want to ditch the `Select` entirely:

```
return db.BrokerOutrights
         .Where(b => b.BidBroker == User.Identity.Name || 
                     b.OfferBroker == User.Identity.Name);
```

If `BrokerOutright` isn't a type that the LINQ provider knows about, you may need to perform the projection in LINQ to Objects instead using `AsEnumerable()` - but then you'd have to return an `IEnumerable<BrokerOutright>` instead of an `IQueryable<BrokerOutright>`.

Comment: Also, if `BrokerOutrights` is framework generated class, you can't use it in the projection.

Comment: it threw me one more error saying The entity or complex type 'WhiteBoardApp.Models.BrokerOutright' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: @Dev: See my edit. (It would help if you'd provide more context...)

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting an anonymous type with `.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Product, x.Term` but the return value of your function is expected to be `BrokerOutright`. It sounds like you probably want to leave the `Select` clause off of your query entirely.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a dynamic type instead of what your method signature says.

Try changing:

```
 .Select(x => new
                {
                    x.Id,
                    x.Product,
                    x.Term 
                }
```

For

```
 .Select(x => new BrokerOutright
                {
                    Id = x.Id,
                    Product = x.Product,
                    Term = x.Term 
                });
```